Capturing the location of a `throw` in unit tests for XCTFail()
I have a helper function for unit tests that runs a closure in a separate Task. If that closure throws, I want to record the error as coming from the location it was thrown, much like Xcode does for a throws test case. To do that I can pass a line and file to XCTFail, but I haven't found any way to find that location.
func process(_ closure: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Void) {
    Task {
        do {
            try await closure()
        } catch {
            XCTFail()  // <--- How I can pass the correct line/file here?
        }
    }
}

final class testTests: XCTestCase {
    enum TestError: Error { case error }

    func testThrowsLocatesErrorCorrectly() async throws {
        let exp = expectation(description: "f() is called")

        process {
            defer { exp.fulfill() }
            print("do things")
            throw TestError.error  // <--- I want Xcode to point here as the error.
        }

        await fulfillment(of: [exp], timeout: 2)
    }
}

The full version of process is inside of a URLProtocol, so it can't return anything (it's called in startLoading()). And it's in a separate file, so no message shows up in Xcode at all in the unit test because the XCTFail is inside the unit test file.
Errors are arbitrary and come from many systems; some Apple, some 3rdparty, some our own. But I don't intend to try to rewrite the many hundreds of specific errors in even our own code, and don't control errors thrown by other code that may bubble up here.
Thread.callStackSymbols does not help since the throw is no longer in the stack.
I could make closure non-throwing and force folks to use XCTAssertNoThrow on every try, but it makes the unit test awkward, losing the benefit of "just throw." For example, nice tools like let x = try XCTUnwrap(...) become let x = XCTAssertNoThrow(try XCTUnwrap(...)).
I've tried dropping the async, and rewriting process this way, but it doesn't improve anything:
func process(_ closure: @escaping @Sendable () throws -> Void) {
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try closure())  // Still puts the error here rather than the throw.
}

I can pass the location to process, but that will only mark the line that calls process, not the line that throws. The closure can be quite long.
I've added an XCTestObservation and inspected the XCTIssue, but it doesn't seem to have anything except the XCTFail line.
Somehow Xcode itself achieves this, but I haven't been able to reverse engineer what they're doing. Maybe something similar to a "Swift Error" breakpoint, but I'm not sure how to reproduce that.

The Swift runtime has a hook, _swift_setWillThrowHandler, which the standard library uses for testing. You could use that hook yourself to record the stack trace when an error is thrown. Turning that stack trace into a useful file name and line number is obviously itself a difficult problem, which is why I'm posting a comment and not an answer.

ah! That's what I figured had to exist. Though I'm betting if I try to use it, Xcode will break me or I would break Xcode. I don't see a way to read the value and chain (though even if I did, I bet Xcode wouldn't :D)  Thanks. It probably won't work, but it's really good info. (The thing I think would work is to use a function macro to find and wrap all try calls in the block with an XCTest reporter, but that won't be available for a while I think.)

This here works for me, provided you have control over the error that's thrown.
enum TestError: Error { case error(file: StaticString, line: UInt) }

func process(_ closure: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Void) {
    Task {
        do {
            try await closure()
        } catch let TestError.error(file, line) {
            XCTFail(file: file, line: line)  // <--- How I can pass the correct line/file here?
        }
    }
}

final class testTests: XCTestCase {

    func testThrowsLocatesErrorCorrectly() async throws {
        let exp = expectation(description: "f() is called")

        process {
            defer { exp.fulfill() }
            print("do things")
            throw TestError.error(file: #filePath, line: #line)  // <--- I want Xcode to point here as the error.
        }

        await fulfillment(of: [exp], timeout: 2)
    }
}

However, I suspect I've stepped around your problem and you can't really rearrange it like this :)

I don't control the error that is thrown. Updated the question to be more clear. There are hundreds or possibly thousands of existing error cases, plus any possible error thrown by Apple or any of our 3rdparty frameworks that might bubble up here.

Can you perhaps repackage it inside your test?

Yes, but it makes the code fragile and difficult to write correctly. I can wrap every throwing call in the block in a XCTAssertNoThrow. But the goal is to allow dozens of developers to write code naturally and have it work in line with how it works in Xcode usually, without special rules for this one little-used case (which no one will remember until we get a very confusing test failure).

If there's a way I could repackage it in process, that would be fine. In fact, that's my goal. Write it once and others are able to not worry about it. But everything I try moves the error into process and loses the information from the original throw.
